# Ubuntu Software center messed icons

Tags: unity, 15.04, software-center, icons

I recently made a movement from Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS to Ubuntu 15.04 and on Ubuntu 15.04 all icons or most of them are messed up, There size is also bigger.On 14.04 there was no such problem. I also tried Ubuntu Mate 15.04 and the problem is same. My question is how to fix that?

Please see the pictures to see the examples

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reinstall the software center ? `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center` Might reset some configs ?

Comment: Same thing. I also made a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 on formated disk and it 's the same

Comment: What about graphics drivers ? Whats your GPU ?

Comment: Related bug report, not fix yet, keep an eye on this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1437856

Comment: My gpu is GTX 760. I use the nouveau drivers

Comment: You should use the nvidia propitiatory driver, it may not fix your issue, but you should have it for that card as nouveau is a community maintained driver and does not support all Nvidia features, for that card i recommend `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346-updates` and a reboot, or see http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers for more options

Comment: Here is my full pc specs:
CPU: FX 8320
CPU Cooler: ZALMAN CNPS10X OPTIMA
MBO: ASUS M5A97 R2.0
RAM: TRANSCEND 2X4 GB 1600 MHZ (8GB)
HDD: WD BLUE 1TB SATA 3
GPU: MSI GTX 760 2GB TF IV GAMING OC
PSU: FORTRON FSP RAIDER 550W 80+ SILVER
CASE: ZALMAN Z3 PLUS ATX USB 3.0

Comment: Only one question: what's the diference beetven  nvidia-346 and nvidia-346-updates. I ask that because in driver manager there is for example nvidia 123 and nvidia 123 updates

Comment: Also same thing with Nvidia

Comment: will this problem be fixed in upcoming 15.10

Comment: Updates will add any new updates for that driver version, as with updating anything, could be bugs. The normal one is considered the most stable but may lack features, they are the same driver version and for the everyday user, there’s nothing to choose really both work very well. I can't tell you if this will be fixed or not, you should ask about it at the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1437856

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the app icon theme cache

  ```
  sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/icon-theme.cache
  ```

  Restart Software center
- Not solved yet, purge its package (let it remove software center & ubuntu-desktop meta pacakge)

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge app-install-data
  ```

  Install it back (this is for Ubuntu/Unity, choose your corresponding one)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  ```

  Start software center